# What is this weird (electrical?) bolt?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I ordered a light fixture from Wayfair. The only installation instructions are a crappy diagram that doesn’t really explain things.

The instructions mention “bolts (2) installed on the ceiling” and “self-tapping screws”. These obviously aren’t the self-tapping screws, but I’m a bit stumped how I’m even supposed to attach them to the “ceiling”… which I assume means “ceiling box”… because the heads of the bolts are smooth and just stamped with a letter “A”. There’s also a “sheath” that apparently fits over the bolt that I’ve never seen either 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Those are expansion bolts.  What you are calling a head is really the end.  The head is the nut and little square.  Something heavy like that light looks, I do not want to depend on drywall only to hold it.  Would return it and get something with proper anchors.  Would also check if it has proper UL listing, so it is legal to even use.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll Google “expansion bolts”… and I’ll be hanging it under a ceiling box, so it’s not going to be hung on the ceiling drywall… but I guess someone would do that if they couldn’t relocate the box? Is that the only reason I would need the expansion bolts?

Comment: Expansion or anchor bolts.  The nut and the A head squeeze the tube together and it pushes out.  Most ceiling are drywall, but they are probably meant for cement/concrete ceilings.

Comment: Is the item UL Listed?  Or CSA/ETL? All of it from the hokey expansion bolts to the fonts used to the Engrish... reek of cheap Cheese from overseas.  (you see the distinctive fonts because Chinese PCs have a few default fonts, and each font includes Roman A-Za-z, and they're "a little off" since it's not a proper Roman font. Note the funny kerning on "Hanging plate".  Anyway, if it isn't UL/ETL/CSA listed, you can't install it in North America and back it goes. NEC 110.2, first rule in the book.

Comment: **IF** you don’t return this, you may want to consider installing a fan-rated junction box to carry what looks to be a bit of weight. Personally, I’d spend the 20 bucks to sleep better at night. (And fan boxes are easy to install.)

Comment: What is the weight of this chandelier? You cannot hang a heavy chandelier from an ordinary ceiling box rated for a light ceiling fixture. Ordinary ceiling boxes are only attached to a ceiling joist on one side. Furthermore some boxes that are supported on both sides are only meant for a light weight fixture.

Comment: Thanks everyone... I totally knew what expansion bolts/anchors are, just had a brain fart. Got up into the attic, and the box itself is pretty heavy duty and attached to two members, I imagine it's ceiling fan rated for sure, so it should have no problem holding the chandelier's weight.

Answer (score 3):

That's a wedge-type wall anchor for masonry. Drill a hole, slip it in, crank it until it expands and binds in the hole.

It's not electrical.

Nor is is suitable for drywall - it will only hold in solid masonry, such as brick or concrete.